# Mongoose - How to initialize a default field value on update bulkOp

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

#### Problem:

Cannot work aggregation in non-existent field.

I have `Follow Schema` which contains the following fields:

```
_user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    following: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
        default: []
    }],
    followers: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
        default: []
    }],
```

And when a user follows someone, I have this:

```
const bulk = Follow.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.find({ _user_id: req.user._id }).upsert().updateOne({
  $addToSet: {
     following: Types.ObjectId(follow_id)
  }
});

bulk.find({ _user_id: Types.ObjectId(follow_id) }).upsert().updateOne({
   $addToSet: {
     followers: req.user._id
   }
});

bulk.execute((err, doc) => {
  ...
})
```

And when this successfully executes, it will be saved in MongoDB.
Now the problem is when the data is just being saved for the first time, the `bulk` op above
only saves the `$addToSet` field specified.
For example, when I run this:

```
bulk.find({ _user_id: Types.ObjectId(follow_id) }).upsert().updateOne({
   $addToSet: {
     followers: req.user._id
   }
});
```

And this will yield to:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(544987dfgsld3),
  followers: [ ObjectId(34578778g6d8f7g6) ] // followers gets saved
            // But how do I initialize the following as empty array? 
}
```

And now I get error in my aggregation because the field is not existent

```
const result = await Follow.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { _user_id: user._id }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        followingCount: { $size: '$following' }, // I get Error here $size field must be array but it doesnt exist
                        followersCount: { $size: '$followers' },
                        followers: 1
                    }
                },
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by checking for non-existent field in my bulkOp query:

```
bulk
  .find({
     _user_id: Types.ObjectId(follow_id),
     following: { // added this block
        $exists: false
     }
})
.upsert()
.updateOne({
   $set: {  // and use $set operator
     following: []
   }
});
```

And a much simpler version using aggregate:

```
{
   $project: {
     following: { $ifNull: ["$following", []] }, // SET DEFAULTS IF NULL OR NON_EXISTENT
     followers: { $ifNull: ["$following", []] },
     followers: 1
   }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    followingCount: { $size: '$following' },
    followersCount: { $size: '$followers' },
    followers: 1
   }
},
```

More info about [$ifNull Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)